# What causes git clone not to bring in the master branch?

Tags: git

Whenever I did a `git clone <Repository SSH URL>`, followed by `git branch`, it will always shows me `master` branch.

Until very recently, I am performing the above same steps for another repository, however I keep getting the `develop` branch instead of the `master` branch.
While I manage to find a solution - `git clone <Repository SSH URL> -b master`, I am wondering what causes `git clone` command to get `develop` branch in the first place?

FYI, both the develop and master branch in the repository are definitely up to date and I am unable to gather much results between this repository and the other repositories (those that give me `master` branch)...

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which [git workflow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/?) is used by the repo's maintainers, the default branch could be anything but `master`. The repo should have some documentation related to their workflow and which branch will be checked out by default. If accessed via GitLab or GitHub, just take a look at the repo's settings to find the default branch.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Doing a `git remote show origin`, it is showing the `develop` as the HEAD branch.. Will check the repository for any documentation..